# NullPointerException for com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Element e)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, itext, openpdf

I'm not exactly sure what this error message is actually pointing to.  To be clear, I know what a NullPointerException is, but I can't figure out what is null that shouldn't be.  Does someone know what causes this error by being null?

Thanks.

```
com.lowagie.text.DocumentException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.add(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.Document.add(Unknown Source)
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.calculateHeights(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.setTotalWidth(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPCell.getMaxHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPRow.calculateHeights(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPRow.getMaxHeights(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.getRowHeight(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.calculateHeights(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable.setTotalWidth(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.goComposite(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.ColumnText.go(Unknown Source)
    at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfDocument.addPTable(Unknown Source)
    ... 97 more
```

The code in question:

```
    this.getDocument().open();
    Element body = this.getBody();
    System.out.println(body);
    System.out.println(this.getDocument().toString());
    this.getDocument().add(body);//it errors out here!
    this.getDocument().close();
```

The debugging statements return:

```
com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfPTable@1fa0c8f
com.lowagie.text.Document@14eb497
```

Comment: I'll guess it's either the PDF document or a table instance.  A spin in a debugger will tell you faster than asking here.

Comment: Do you have the piece of code that is calling the `PdfDocument.add()` method?

Comment: Thought that as well, but System.out.println(); of both the table and the document give pointers to non null objects of the correct types.

Comment: In any case: the moment I see my name in your package names, I see that you are using a version of iText that is at least 7 years old. As the author of that software I strongly recommend to use a more recent version. You are fooling your employer/customers by introducing such an old version into your project/product. That version is no longer supported and has some legal issues too. Stop using it!

Comment: ok, I suppose that is good to know...

Comment: What is the latest version compatible with java 6?

Comment: iText 5.5.9 is compatible with Java 5, so *a fortiori*, it's also compatible with Java 6.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same error and stack trace, and solved the problem by switching to OpenPDF.

OpenPDF is based on iText 4 and has some additional bug-fixes and NPE-fixes.
OpenPDF is being actively maintained.

https://github.com/LibrePDF/OpenPDF